# Scripting keeps by-passing the if statement when running in the shell

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am working on a very common assignment for my Unix class that asks me to do the following.

> Write a shell script that loops through all of its arguments using $*. Treat each of these arguments
> as if it were a user name in the Unix server, though one or two may not be. The script should
> also perform following tasks:
> If the username is not in /etc/passwd, then the script reports that they are not in the password
> file.
> If the username is flagged as disabled, then the script reports that the account is
> disabled.

I wrote the following script:

```
read -p "Please input a user name: "
cat /etc/passwd | grep "$*" wc -l > compare

if [[ $compare == 0 ]]
then echo "Username not found."

else
cat compare | grep "disabled" | wc -l

fi
```

My idea was simple. Turn the result of the WC into a number. If it found the user it would produce a 1, if not a zero. Compare that number in an if statement and nest if statements inside each other to pull off the instructions. Unfortunately, the script seems to skip over the first if statement that compares the value of the compare file to zero. My question is does anyone see why my script is skipping the if case and going right to the elif? If I can nail that down I feel like I can complete this part of the assignment.

Thank you for considering this request and any help you can give!

Comment: You are creating a *file* named `compare` (with `> compare`), but you are trying to evaluate a *variable* named compare in your `if` statement (with `if [[ $compare == 0 ]]`.  They are two completely different things.

Comment: there are several other syntax errors. Learn to check you code at http://shellcheck.net. The explanations provided can be a little obscure, but slow down and think about where/what is being highlighted as an error and then compare your code to another small sample of code that is known to be working (even if that other code is not providing you the exact feature you want). Good luck.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you.

Comment: .... and please, don't abuse the `cat`, pass the filename as an argument to `grep` instead.